# Compress backup taken from two different environments take different time to restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, restore, azure-vm

I have two backup files one from Normal SQL Server and one from SQL Server from Azure VM.

The restore of these backup files is totally different from each other. Though the database backups are performed at the same state, meaning the Normal Servers backup is being first restored on Azure VM1 took 20 Minutes. and then took backup of Azure VM1 and restoring it on VM2 took 1 Hour and 30 minutes.

To be more clear on the above point, I haven't started any writes on Azure VM1 before taking backup again.

Can anyone shed some light on what is different when we are taking backup from Azure VM and restoring it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is instant file initialization enabled ? If not, please enable it by giving PERFORM VOLUME MAINTENANCE rights to SQL server service account.

Comment: Is the size of the backup files similar? If not that would be an important clue.

Comment: @usr:Yes the backup file size is same.

Comment: @Kin: No the instant file initialization is not enabled but could you please help me understand it, how does it different on Azure. Why I need to enable it on Azure only. as it is not enabled on my old Normal servers. I have read about this best practice and thank you for the hint. but really want to understand how much difference will it make.